# Convert Mysql stored data to correct utf8

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8

I stored large Arabic database in Mysql using Perl in wrong format, here what happened:

1)-Mysql tables created with attributes:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

2)-My perl scripts are created in utf8 and I use "use utf8;" at the top.

3)-I can read the data from the table and display it normal in Arabic on html pages using charset utf8 meta tag.

The problem when I see the data in the database it is stored as encoded not readable, after search about Perl module DBI, I found I should do this:

```
$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;
$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Immediately after connecting to the database which I did not do.

Now if I do this, the new data stored in the table are shown correct everywhere even in the mysql browser windows application.

The problem now with the already data stored in the table, it seems it comes double utf8 encode or something like that. How to fix the already stored data when the above flags were not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of search, did not find anyway to fix the data in mysql direct or using programming like Perl.

The only solution I did is to export the data from mysql the same way I put it in which seems to be double utf8 encoded by Perl to text files but after I utf8 decode it in Perl first.

After that the data is correctly saved to text files in UTF8 format which can be imported or managed direct as a valid UTF8 data in Perl and mysql.